# Windows 10 May 2019 update taking forever

Tags: windows-10

So, I have an Alienware x51 R3 computer which has a GTX 1060 6GB factory overclock from EVGA as well as an i7 6700k @4.0 GHz and 8GB of RAM.
I ran Windows 10 Update Assistant because I want to update to the May 2019 update. It downloaded and verified within 5 minutes, then when it got to the final portion after downloading and verifying (before it reboots) it got stuck at 99% for over six hours. I received a UAC prompt within 7 to 9 hours I believe but made the mistake of rebooting about 30 minutes after confirming it because the update assistant was still at 99%. This is very strange because my grandma's computer completed the upgrade in 45 minutes and she has an i5 at somewhere between 2-3 GHz I believe and 6GB RAM.

I tried a suggestion by Microsoft to go into `C:\$GetCurrent` and copy the `media` folder to the desktop. Then reboot, copy it back into the folder, and run the setup in there. I did so VIA TeamViewer since I was at school and when I got home within 7 hours of leaving it running, the screen for "Installing Windows 10" was only at 3% complete.

How can I speed this up dramatically? The install time is atrocious.

Comment: There isn't exactly a way of speeding it up. My question is why would you restart when it's updating? Windows has told you to not restart for years.

Comment: It wasn't telling me not to restart, it was still at the Windows 10 Update Assistant on the Desktop.

Comment: Oh right ok sorry for the assumption.

Comment: The amount of time is entirely based on the amount of data that your profile might have.  When a feature upgrade is installed your profile is migrated to the new installation.  If you performed a reboot before the feature upgrade was actually ready to proceed to the installation phase you likely interrupted it.  There is no method to speed the process up.  However, it's possible the upgrade taking this long, is a symptom of another problem